# A question related to distributive bounded lattice.

Tags: lattice-orders

If L is a distributive bounded lattice then show that the complemented elements of L form a sublattice of L.
The question is very simple to understand but I am not confirm about my answer.
My question is Can I give an example to show this ? Or I have to prove this in general ? Can giving a particular example will be all good for this question? If not, I have no idea to prove this by other way.

Comment: You don't prove a general claim by giving an example.

Comment: Looking for appriopriate answer.

Comment: Take your lattice $L$, and then collect together all the complemented elements $C = \{ x\in L : (\exists y\in L) x\lor y = 1 \text{ and } x \land y = 0\}$. This is a subset of $L$, so, show it is a sublattice, i.e. show it contains $0,1$ and is closed under $\lor$ and $\land$.